# MySQL into outfile formatting

Tags: mysql, select, select-into, select-into-outfile

```
select * 
  INTO OUTFILE 'outfile.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED by ','
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  from nGrams
```

Is there any way I can modify this query to return each row on one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like thats exactly what it would do already.

However, if you are doing this on Windows, you might want to use `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'` or some crappy text editors (e.g. notepad) might not see `\n` by itself as a line break