# How to format results from a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql

I have the following table within my database. I need to write a store procedure that will send all the data to a text file. The following works, however, I would like to format in such way that every row in the database should correspond to a line in the text file. Here is my stored procedure and a picture of my database:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `outPutTweets`()
BEGIN

SELECT tweetID, accountName, tweet, DATE_FORMAT(Time,'%H:%i') INTO OUTFILE 'C:/xampp/htdocs/Dropbox/SportsMedia/ScrollbarProject/results.txt'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
From tweets ORDER by Time desc;
END
```

[image]

Comment: and what is wrong with file you're getting with this stored proc?

Comment: What do you mean, correspond to a line in the text file? You mean adding a line feed at the end? Can you show us an example of what you want.

Comment: @Lashane everything is printed within the same line

Comment: No, maybe your text editor does not understand `\n`, but row in database = line in file

Comment: I thik your code is correct! If you are using windows try this `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' `

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL into outfile formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750970/mysql-into-outfile-formatting)

Comment: @Lashane you are totally right, I just tested in a different text editor and it works the way I want

Comment: @Athafoud The problem was my text editor

Comment: @Athafoud I just added \r and it works in both of my text editors. And yeah my pc is a windows. thank you